# WSO2 mediator deploying and pointing resources

Tags: deployment, resources, wso2, mediator

I developed my mediator in which I used  an xsd file to validate my xml request.

The code I used is the one below:

```
   SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);           
        Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File("SubscriptionRequest.xsd"));
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
```

Where `SubscriptionRequest.xsd` is the schema file used for validation.

I'm using eclipse `Wso2 Studio` and the xsd file is in the /src directory.
The code above cannot find the file, so how can I deploy and point this resource programmatically? 
Do I have to put it inside the registry?

Comment: Solved:     Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("SubscriptionRequest.xsd"));

Comment: Great. Please post your solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("SubscriptionR‌​equest.xsd"));